# Longtable landscape

Tags: sidewaystable

In the following [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632327/fitting-long-table-possibly-in-one-page?noredirect=1#comment1576943_632327) I asked help regarding a long table. The MWE, reported there is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textfont=it,
            labelsep=newline, 
            justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{ skip=1.4pt, labelfont=sc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx 
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, ltablex, makecell, multirow}  % <---
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{amsmath,ragged2e} % <-- new
\usepackage{interval,pbox}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\Quad[1][1]{\foreach \Quaddy in {1,...,#1}{\quad}\ignorespaces}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}, 
         table-format=1.3, 
         table-space-text-post=***,
         table-number-alignment =center}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}
{\hspace*{1.5cm}}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\hyphenation{bur-kina}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\note:TBW   \\
    \item[*]    $p<0.5$
    \item[**]   $p<0.1$
    \item[***]  $p<0.01$
\end{TableNotes}
%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X *{5}{d{3.5}}}
\caption{OLS estimation - Dependent variable std\_gpa \label{OLSstd}}   \\
    \toprule
    &   \mc{(1)}    &   \mc{(2)}    &   \mc{(3)}    &   \mc{(4)}    &   \mc{(5)}    \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{OLS estimation - Dependent variable std\_gpa \label{OLSstd} (continue)}   \\
    \toprule
    &   \mc{(1)}    &   \mc{(2)}    &   \mc{(3)}    &   \mc{(4)}    &   \mc{(5)}    \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes   \\
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\textit{Continue on next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
autonuni    &  0.020    &  0.019    &  0.013    &   0.011   &   0.011           \\
            & (0.013)   & (0.013)   & (0.013)   &  (0.013)  &  (0.013)          \\
    \addlinespace
female      &           &  0.168\sym{***}  
                                    &   0.129\sym{***}  
                                                &  0.127\sym{***}  
                                                            &   0.138\sym{***}  \\
            &           & (0.046)   &  (0.042)  & (0.044)   &  (0.041)          \\
    \addlinespace
z\_age      &           & -1.142\sym{**} 
                                    & -1.070\sym{**} 
                                                & -1.122\sym{**} 
                                                            & -0.977\sym{*}     \\
            &           & (0.564)   & (0.518)   & (0.519)   & (0.521)           \\
    \addlinespace
z\_age2     &           &  1.113\sym{*}  
                                    &  1.044\sym{*}  
                                                &  1.098\sym{**} 
                                                            &  0.957\sym{*}     \\
            &           & (0.570)   & (0.523)   & (0.523)   & (0.525)           \\
    \addlinespace
school\_scientlic
            &           & -0.083    & -0.081    & -0.089    & -0.091\sym{*}     \\
            &           & (0.057)   & (0.056)   & (0.056)   & (0.053)           \\
    \addlinespace
school\_otherlic    &   & -0.179\sym{***}
                                    & -0.173\sym{***}
                                                & -0.178\sym{***}
                                                            & -0.169\sym{***}   \\
            &           & (0.039)   & (0.039)   & (0.037)   & (0.040)           \\
    \addlinespace
school\_techvoc
            &           & -0.332\sym{***}
                                    & -0.338\sym{***}
                                                & -0.338\sym{***}
                                                            & -0.345\sym{***}   \\
            &           & (0.066)   & (0.065)   & (0.060)   & (0.059)           \\
    \addlinespace
z\_e        &           &           & -0.026    & -0.024    & -0.023            \\
            &           &           & (0.019)   & (0.019)   & (0.019)           \\
    \addlinespace
z\_a        &           &           & -0.040\sym{*}  
                                                & -0.042\sym{*}  
                                                            & -0.038            \\
            &           &           & (0.023)   & (0.023)   & (0.023)           \\
    \addlinespace
z\_c        &           &           & 0.094\sym{***}
                                                & 0.093\sym{***}
                                                            & 0.091\sym{***}    \\
            &           &           & (0.017)   & (0.017)   & (0.017)           \\
    \addlinespace
z\_n        &           &           & -0.034    & -0.029    & -0.028            \\
            &           &           & (0.024)   & (0.023)   & (0.022)           \\
    \addlinespace
z\_o        &           &           &  0.037\sym{**} 
                                                &  0.036\sym{**} 
                                                            &  0.037\sym{**}    \\
            &           &           & (0.018)   & (0.017)   & (0.017)           \\
    \addlinespace
edufat\_high    &       &           &           &  0.037    &  0.026            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.040)   & (0.039)           \\
    \addlinespace
edufat\_l   &           &           &           & -0.042    & -0.048            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.053)   & (0.055)           \\
    \addlinespace
edumot\_high    &       &           &           & -0.039    & -0.048            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.050)   & (0.050)           \\
edumot\_l   &           &           &           & 0.099     &  0.085            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.062)   & (0.059)           \\
    \addlinespace
occupfat\_d2    &       &           &           & -0.059    & -0.055            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.054)   & (0.055)           \\
    \addlinespace
occupfat\_d3    &       &           &           & -0.164\sym{***}
                                                            & -0.159\sym{**}    \\
            &           &           &           & (0.059)   & (0.059)           \\
    \addlinespace
occupfat\_d4    &       &           &           &  0.084    &  0.087            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.157)   & (0.155)           \\
    \addlinespace
occupfat\_d5    &       &           &           & -0.282\sym{***}
                                                            & -0.288\sym{***}   \\
            &           &           &           & (0.070)   & (0.073)           \\
    \addlinespace
occupmot\_d2    &       &           &           & -0.062    & -0.051            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.038)   & (0.038)           \\
    \addlinespace
occupmot\_d3    &       &           &           & -0.150\sym{**} 
                                                            & -0.135\sym{*}     \\
            &           &           &           & (0.068)   & (0.069)           \\
    \addlinespace
occupmot\_d4    &       &           &           &  0.063    &  0.061            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.054)   & (0.054)           \\
    \addlinespace
occupmot\_d5    &       &           &           &  0.024    &  0.027            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.181)   & (0.178)           \\
    \addlinespace
jobsectfat\_d2  &       &           &           & -0.011    & -0.015            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.060)   & (0.061)           \\
    \addlinespace
jobsectfat\_d3  &       &           &           & -0.035    & -0.041            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.077)   & (0.076)           \\
    \addlinespace
jobsectfat\_d4  &       &           &           & -0.037    & -0.034            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.044)   & (0.045)           \\
    \addlinespace
jobsectmot\_d2  &       &           &           &  0.063    &  0.072            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.119)   & (0.117)           \\
    \addlinespace
jobsectmot\_d3  &       &           &           &  0.211    &  0.184            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.155)   & (0.155)           \\
    \addlinespace
jobsectmot\_d4  &       &           &           & -0.029    & -0.018            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.043)   & (0.044)           \\
    \addlinespace
resid\_provme   &       &           &           &           &  0.002            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.033)           \\
    \addlinespace
resid\_othersicily  &   &           &           &           & -0.084            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.062)           \\
    \addlinespace
resid\_rc   &           &           &           &           &  0.004            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.079)           \\
    \addlinespace
resid\_provrc   &       &           &           &           & -0.175\sym{***}   \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.062)           \\
    \addlinespace
resid\_othercalabria    
            &           &           &           &           & -0.374\sym{***}   \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.093)           \\
    \addlinespace
resid\_otheritaly   &   &           &           &           & 0.035             \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.227)           \\
    \midrule
\(N\)       & \mc{3242} & \mc{3242} & \mc{3242} & \mc{3242} & \mc{3242}         \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

Since I need to add extra columns I would like to use a landscape orientation. I tried to envelope the portion starting from ThreePartTable within sidewaystable environment, but it does not work. Any help?

Comment: With `longtable`, you should use `threeparttablex`. Beware the syntax is slighly different.

Comment: Insert your table in `landscape` environment: `\begin{landscape} <table> \end{landscape}` For it you already load `pdflscape` package.

Comment: @Zarko, Thank you so much. I was insisting with sidewaystable, while landscape solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is already solved by my comment above, however let me add some off-topic  suggestion:

- If you willing to replace `threeparttable` with `longtblr` table environment defined in the `tabularray` package, the table code become shorter and more clear:
- Using `longtblr` you can add more columns to table with accordingly changed option `colspec`.
- existing MWE written by use of `longblr` is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textfont=it,
            labelsep=newline,
            justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{ skip=1.4pt, labelfont=sc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}  % <---
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {3}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         table-format={(}1.3{***},
         input-open-uncertainty =,
         input-close-uncertainty=,
         }

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
%
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {OLS estimation - Dependent variable std\_gpa},
  label = {OLSstd},
  remark{Note} = {TBW\\ 
                  $^*p<0.1;~^{**}p<0.05;~^{***}p<0.01$.},
                    ]{%colsep = 4pt,
                      colspec = {@{} X *{5}{S} @{}},
                     row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                     row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=1ex},
                      rowhead = 1,
                     }
    \toprule
% column headers
            & {{{(1)}}} & {{{(2)}}} & {{{(3)}}} & {{{(4)}}} & {{{(5)}}} \\
    \midrule
% table body
autonuni    &  0.020    &  0.019    &  0.013    &   0.011   &   0.011           \\
            & (0.013)   & (0.013)   & (0.013)   &  (0.013)  &  (0.013)          \\

female      &           &  0.168\TblrNote{***}
                                    &   0.129\TblrNote{***}
                                                &  0.127\TblrNote{***}
                                                            &   0.138\TblrNote{***}  \\
            &           & (0.046)   &  (0.042)  & (0.044)   &  (0.041)          \\

z\_age      &           & -1.142\TblrNote{**}
                                    & -1.070\TblrNote{**}
                                                & -1.122\TblrNote{**}
                                                            & -0.977\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.564)   & (0.518)   & (0.519)   & (0.521)           \\

z\_age2     &           &  1.113\TblrNote{*}
                                    &  1.044\TblrNote{*}
                                                &  1.098\TblrNote{**}
                                                            &  0.957\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.570)   & (0.523)   & (0.523)   & (0.525)           \\

school\_scientlic
            &           & -0.083    & -0.081    & -0.089    & -0.091\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.057)   & (0.056)   & (0.056)   & (0.053)           \\

school\_otherlic    &   & -0.179\TblrNote{***}
                                    & -0.173\TblrNote{***}
                                                & -0.178\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.169\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           & (0.039)   & (0.039)   & (0.037)   & (0.040)           \\

school\_techvoc
            &           & -0.332\TblrNote{***}
                                    & -0.338\TblrNote{***}
                                                & -0.338\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.345\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           & (0.066)   & (0.065)   & (0.060)   & (0.059)           \\

z\_e        &           &           & -0.026    & -0.024    & -0.023            \\
            &           &           & (0.019)   & (0.019)   & (0.019)           \\

z\_a        &           &           & -0.040\TblrNote{*}
                                                & -0.042\TblrNote{*}
                                                            & -0.038            \\
            &           &           & (0.023)   & (0.023)   & (0.023)           \\

z\_c        &           &           & 0.094\TblrNote{***}
                                                & 0.093\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & 0.091\TblrNote{***}    \\
            &           &           & (0.017)   & (0.017)   & (0.017)           \\

z\_n        &           &           & -0.034    & -0.029    & -0.028            \\
            &           &           & (0.024)   & (0.023)   & (0.022)           \\

z\_o        &           &           &  0.037\TblrNote{**}
                                                &  0.036\TblrNote{**}
                                                            &  0.037\TblrNote{**}    \\
            &           &           & (0.018)   & (0.017)   & (0.017)           \\

edufat\_high    &       &           &           &  0.037    &  0.026            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.040)   & (0.039)           \\

edufat\_l   &           &           &           & -0.042    & -0.048            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.053)   & (0.055)           \\

edumot\_high    &       &           &           & -0.039    & -0.048            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.050)   & (0.050)           \\
edumot\_l   &           &           &           & 0.099     &  0.085            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.062)   & (0.059)           \\

occupfat\_d2    &       &           &           & -0.059    & -0.055            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.054)   & (0.055)           \\

occupfat\_d3    &       &           &           & -0.164\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.159\TblrNote{**}    \\
            &           &           &           & (0.059)   & (0.059)           \\

occupfat\_d4    &       &           &           &  0.084    &  0.087            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.157)   & (0.155)           \\

occupfat\_d5    &       &           &           & -0.282\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.288\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           & (0.070)   & (0.073)           \\

occupmot\_d2    &       &           &           & -0.062    & -0.051            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.038)   & (0.038)           \\

occupmot\_d3    &       &           &           & -0.150\TblrNote{**}
                                                            & -0.135\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           &           &           & (0.068)   & (0.069)           \\

occupmot\_d4    &       &           &           &  0.063    &  0.061            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.054)   & (0.054)           \\

occupmot\_d5    &       &           &           &  0.024    &  0.027            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.181)   & (0.178)           \\

jobsectfat\_d2  &       &           &           & -0.011    & -0.015            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.060)   & (0.061)           \\

jobsectfat\_d3  &       &           &           & -0.035    & -0.041            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.077)   & (0.076)           \\

jobsectfat\_d4  &       &           &           & -0.037    & -0.034            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.044)   & (0.045)           \\

jobsectmot\_d2  &       &           &           &  0.063    &  0.072            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.119)   & (0.117)           \\

jobsectmot\_d3  &       &           &           &  0.211    &  0.184            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.155)   & (0.155)           \\

jobsectmot\_d4  &       &           &           & -0.029    & -0.018            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.043)   & (0.044)           \\

resid\_provme   &       &           &           &           &  0.002            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.033)           \\

resid\_othersicily  &   &           &           &           & -0.084            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.062)           \\

resid\_rc   &           &           &           &           &  0.004            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.079)           \\

resid\_provrc   &       &           &           &           & -0.175\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.062)           \\

resid\_othercalabria
            &           &           &           &           & -0.374\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.093)           \\
    
resid\_otheritaly   &   &           &           &           & 0.035             \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.227)           \\
    \midrule
\(N\)       &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}}         \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]