# Rotating a longtblr without rotating the page

Tags: landscape, tabularray

I have read several discussions about ways to produce rotated long tables.

I am specially interested in the fact that `pdflscape` can produce a working solution, as in:
[Longtable landscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643239/longtable-landscape)

However, I would like the page **not** to be in landscape mode at the end, as it is not compatible with PDF/A generation.

Would there be a way to rotate specifically those lanscape pages?

I can imagine that the page numbering would be wrongly placed, but if this is the only issue, this is fine to me.

I am using the MWE from the indicated link:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textfont=it,
            labelsep=newline,
            justification=centering]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{ skip=1.4pt, labelfont=sc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}  % <---
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {3}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         table-format={(}1.3{***},
         input-open-uncertainty =,
         input-close-uncertainty=,
         }

\begin{document}

%%% <- HERE ADD A COMMAND TO START ROTATING THE LANDSCAPE PAGES %%%

    \begin{landscape}
%
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {OLS estimation - Dependent variable std\_gpa},
  label = {OLSstd},
  remark{Note} = {TBW\\ 
                  $^*p<0.1;~^{**}p<0.05;~^{***}p<0.01$.},
                    ]{%colsep = 4pt,
                      colspec = {@{} X *{5}{S} @{}},
                     row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                     row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=1ex},
                      rowhead = 1,
                     }
    \toprule
% column headers
            & {{{(1)}}} & {{{(2)}}} & {{{(3)}}} & {{{(4)}}} & {{{(5)}}} \\
    \midrule
% table body
autonuni    &  0.020    &  0.019    &  0.013    &   0.011   &   0.011           \\
            & (0.013)   & (0.013)   & (0.013)   &  (0.013)  &  (0.013)          \\

female      &           &  0.168\TblrNote{***}
                                    &   0.129\TblrNote{***}
                                                &  0.127\TblrNote{***}
                                                            &   0.138\TblrNote{***}  \\
            &           & (0.046)   &  (0.042)  & (0.044)   &  (0.041)          \\

z\_age      &           & -1.142\TblrNote{**}
                                    & -1.070\TblrNote{**}
                                                & -1.122\TblrNote{**}
                                                            & -0.977\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.564)   & (0.518)   & (0.519)   & (0.521)           \\

z\_age2     &           &  1.113\TblrNote{*}
                                    &  1.044\TblrNote{*}
                                                &  1.098\TblrNote{**}
                                                            &  0.957\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.570)   & (0.523)   & (0.523)   & (0.525)           \\

school\_scientlic
            &           & -0.083    & -0.081    & -0.089    & -0.091\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.057)   & (0.056)   & (0.056)   & (0.053)           \\

school\_otherlic    &   & -0.179\TblrNote{***}
                                    & -0.173\TblrNote{***}
                                                & -0.178\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.169\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           & (0.039)   & (0.039)   & (0.037)   & (0.040)           \\

school\_techvoc
            &           & -0.332\TblrNote{***}
                                    & -0.338\TblrNote{***}
                                                & -0.338\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.345\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           & (0.066)   & (0.065)   & (0.060)   & (0.059)           \\

z\_e        &           &           & -0.026    & -0.024    & -0.023            \\
            &           &           & (0.019)   & (0.019)   & (0.019)           \\

z\_a        &           &           & -0.040\TblrNote{*}
                                                & -0.042\TblrNote{*}
                                                            & -0.038            \\
            &           &           & (0.023)   & (0.023)   & (0.023)           \\

z\_c        &           &           & 0.094\TblrNote{***}
                                                & 0.093\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & 0.091\TblrNote{***}    \\
            &           &           & (0.017)   & (0.017)   & (0.017)           \\

z\_n        &           &           & -0.034    & -0.029    & -0.028            \\
            &           &           & (0.024)   & (0.023)   & (0.022)           \\

z\_o        &           &           &  0.037\TblrNote{**}
                                                &  0.036\TblrNote{**}
                                                            &  0.037\TblrNote{**}    \\
            &           &           & (0.018)   & (0.017)   & (0.017)           \\

edufat\_high    &       &           &           &  0.037    &  0.026            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.040)   & (0.039)           \\

edufat\_l   &           &           &           & -0.042    & -0.048            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.053)   & (0.055)           \\

edumot\_high    &       &           &           & -0.039    & -0.048            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.050)   & (0.050)           \\
edumot\_l   &           &           &           & 0.099     &  0.085            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.062)   & (0.059)           \\

occupfat\_d2    &       &           &           & -0.059    & -0.055            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.054)   & (0.055)           \\

occupfat\_d3    &       &           &           & -0.164\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.159\TblrNote{**}    \\
            &           &           &           & (0.059)   & (0.059)           \\

occupfat\_d4    &       &           &           &  0.084    &  0.087            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.157)   & (0.155)           \\

occupfat\_d5    &       &           &           & -0.282\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.288\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           & (0.070)   & (0.073)           \\

occupmot\_d2    &       &           &           & -0.062    & -0.051            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.038)   & (0.038)           \\

occupmot\_d3    &       &           &           & -0.150\TblrNote{**}
                                                            & -0.135\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           &           &           & (0.068)   & (0.069)           \\

occupmot\_d4    &       &           &           &  0.063    &  0.061            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.054)   & (0.054)           \\

occupmot\_d5    &       &           &           &  0.024    &  0.027            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.181)   & (0.178)           \\

jobsectfat\_d2  &       &           &           & -0.011    & -0.015            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.060)   & (0.061)           \\

jobsectfat\_d3  &       &           &           & -0.035    & -0.041            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.077)   & (0.076)           \\

jobsectfat\_d4  &       &           &           & -0.037    & -0.034            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.044)   & (0.045)           \\

jobsectmot\_d2  &       &           &           &  0.063    &  0.072            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.119)   & (0.117)           \\

jobsectmot\_d3  &       &           &           &  0.211    &  0.184            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.155)   & (0.155)           \\

jobsectmot\_d4  &       &           &           & -0.029    & -0.018            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.043)   & (0.044)           \\

resid\_provme   &       &           &           &           &  0.002            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.033)           \\

resid\_othersicily  &   &           &           &           & -0.084            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.062)           \\

resid\_rc   &           &           &           &           &  0.004            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.079)           \\

resid\_provrc   &       &           &           &           & -0.175\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.062)           \\

resid\_othercalabria
            &           &           &           &           & -0.374\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.093)           \\
    
resid\_otheritaly   &   &           &           &           & 0.035             \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.227)           \\
    \midrule
\(N\)       &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}}         \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}

%%% <- HERE ADD A COMMAND TO STOP ROTATING THE LANDSCAPE PAGES %%%

\end{document}
```

---

### Updates

I have added an image to better explain the desired result:
[image: Desired page orientation]

Comment: Background of your desired table is unknown. Do you really need so wide first column? It seems that it occupy half of table width, but showed text it very narrow (about 8em). So it can perfectly fit in portrait page. About rotating. Your question is unclear. See, if you replace `pdflscape` with `lscape` are than result is what is looking for?

Comment: Many thanks @Zarko, I have provided an image to answer the question "What you mean by rotating of table but not a page?".

Comment: That Exactly is provided in my answer ...

Comment: Do you check my comment and meanwhile provided answer? As I see in answer I addresses many issues of your question and provide solution for them. So far you not response on it. So it is now unclear what you after.

Comment: the expected result is actually what (pdf)lscape produces, it only rotates the body leaving the page head/foot in portrait. pdlscape additionally adds a pdfmark to suggest to a viewer that the page view is landscape, some pdf readers use this, some guess that anyway as most of the text is that way up. You can try the original lscape package which doesn't give that hint, although your viewer may rotate anyway

Comment: @Zarko and @David Carlisle, thank you very much for your help. Using `lscape`/`pdflscape` did solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To long for the comment ...

- As I already mentioned in my comment, a background of your desired table is unknown:

  - Do you really need so wide first column (Its width is almost of the table width, but showed text it very narrow (about 8em).
  - As is provided MWE, used table code can perfectly fit in portrait page.
  - What you mean by rotating of table but not a page? This
    demand is unclear. It seems that you like that page with table should not be rotated (for more easing reading) but stay in form as it appear printed version of document.
  - If the aforementioned is the case, than your problem has is not the table code but used package for landscape   pages: instead of `pdflscape` you should use `lscape`!
- Below are two examples. In the first, complete MWE is provided code for table set on portrait oriented pages, in the second are shown only needed changes if you persist to rotate tabel on page:

```
\RequirePackage{etex}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textfont=it,             % not used in this MWE
%            labelsep=newline,
%            justification=centering]{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{ skip=1.4pt, labelfont=sc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{conthead-text}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
%----------------
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         table-format={(}-1.3{$^{***}$},
         input-open-uncertainty =,
         input-close-uncertainty=,
         table-align-text-before = false
         }

    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {OLS estimation - Dependent variable std\_gpa},
  label = {OLSstd},
remark{Note} = {\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{
                TBW
                $^*:\ p<0.1;\quad ^{**}:\ p<0.05;\quad ^{***}:\ p<0.01$.}
                },
                    ]{colspec  = {@{} X[2.5,l] *{5}{X[c, h, si]} @{}},
                      row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                        row{1} = {guard},
                  row{even[3]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                      rowhead  = 1,
                     }
    \toprule
% column headers
            &   (1)     &   (2)     &   (3)     &   (4)     &   (5)             \\
    \midrule
% table body
autonuni    &  0.020    &  0.019    &  0.013    &   0.011   &   0.011           \\
            & (0.013)   & (0.013)   & (0.013)   &  (0.013)  &  (0.013)          \\

female      &           &  0.168\TblrNote{***}
                                    &   0.129\TblrNote{***}
                                                &  0.127\TblrNote{***}
                                                            &   0.138\TblrNote{***}  \\
            &           & (0.046)   &  (0.042)  & (0.044)   &  (0.041)          \\

z\_age      &           & -1.142\TblrNote{**}
                                    & -1.070\TblrNote{**}
                                                & -1.122\TblrNote{**}
                                                            & -0.977\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.564)   & (0.518)   & (0.519)   & (0.521)           \\

z\_age2     &           &  1.113\TblrNote{*}
                                    &  1.044\TblrNote{*}
                                                &  1.098\TblrNote{**}
                                                            &  0.957\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.570)   & (0.523)   & (0.523)   & (0.525)           \\

school\_scientlic
            &           & -0.083    & -0.081    & -0.089    & -0.091\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           & (0.057)   & (0.056)   & (0.056)   & (0.053)           \\

school\_otherlic    &   & -0.179\TblrNote{***}
                                    & -0.173\TblrNote{***}
                                                & -0.178\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.169\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           & (0.039)   & (0.039)   & (0.037)   & (0.040)           \\

school\_techvoc
            &           & -0.332\TblrNote{***}
                                    & -0.338\TblrNote{***}
                                                & -0.338\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.345\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           & (0.066)   & (0.065)   & (0.060)   & (0.059)           \\

z\_e        &           &           & -0.026    & -0.024    & -0.023            \\
            &           &           & (0.019)   & (0.019)   & (0.019)           \\

z\_a        &           &           & -0.040\TblrNote{*}
                                                & -0.042\TblrNote{*}
                                                            & -0.038            \\
            &           &           & (0.023)   & (0.023)   & (0.023)           \\

z\_c        &           &           & 0.094\TblrNote{***}
                                                & 0.093\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & 0.091\TblrNote{***}    \\
            &           &           & (0.017)   & (0.017)   & (0.017)           \\

z\_n        &           &           & -0.034    & -0.029    & -0.028            \\
            &           &           & (0.024)   & (0.023)   & (0.022)           \\

z\_o        &           &           &  0.037\TblrNote{**}
                                                &  0.036\TblrNote{**}
                                                            &  0.037\TblrNote{**}    \\
            &           &           & (0.018)   & (0.017)   & (0.017)           \\

edufat\_high    &       &           &           &  0.037    &  0.026            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.040)   & (0.039)           \\

edufat\_l   &           &           &           & -0.042    & -0.048            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.053)   & (0.055)           \\

edumot\_high    &       &           &           & -0.039    & -0.048            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.050)   & (0.050)           \\
edumot\_l   &           &           &           & 0.099     &  0.085            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.062)   & (0.059)           \\

occupfat\_d2    &       &           &           & -0.059    & -0.055            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.054)   & (0.055)           \\

occupfat\_d3    &       &           &           & -0.164\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.159\TblrNote{**}    \\
            &           &           &           & (0.059)   & (0.059)           \\

occupfat\_d4    &       &           &           &  0.084    &  0.087            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.157)   & (0.155)           \\

occupfat\_d5    &       &           &           & -0.282\TblrNote{***}
                                                            & -0.288\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           & (0.070)   & (0.073)           \\

occupmot\_d2    &       &           &           & -0.062    & -0.051            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.038)   & (0.038)           \\

occupmot\_d3    &       &           &           & -0.150\TblrNote{**}
                                                            & -0.135\TblrNote{*}     \\
            &           &           &           & (0.068)   & (0.069)           \\

occupmot\_d4    &       &           &           &  0.063    &  0.061            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.054)   & (0.054)           \\

occupmot\_d5    &       &           &           &  0.024    &  0.027            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.181)   & (0.178)           \\

jobsectfat\_d2  &       &           &           & -0.011    & -0.015            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.060)   & (0.061)           \\

jobsectfat\_d3  &       &           &           & -0.035    & -0.041            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.077)   & (0.076)           \\

jobsectfat\_d4  &       &           &           & -0.037    & -0.034            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.044)   & (0.045)           \\

jobsectmot\_d2  &       &           &           &  0.063    &  0.072            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.119)   & (0.117)           \\

jobsectmot\_d3  &       &           &           &  0.211    &  0.184            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.155)   & (0.155)           \\

jobsectmot\_d4  &       &           &           & -0.029    & -0.018            \\
            &           &           &           & (0.043)   & (0.044)           \\

resid\_provme   &       &           &           &           &  0.002            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.033)           \\

resid\_othersicily  &   &           &           &           & -0.084            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.062)           \\

resid\_rc   &           &           &           &           &  0.004            \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.079)           \\

resid\_provrc   &       &           &           &           & -0.175\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.062)           \\

resid\_othercalabria
            &           &           &           &           & -0.374\TblrNote{***}   \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.093)           \\

resid\_otheritaly   &   &           &           &           & 0.035             \\
            &           &           &           &           & (0.227)           \\
    \midrule
\(N\)       &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}} &{{{3242}}}         \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second example, where table is rotated on the page, than you need to insert `lscape` package in document preamble and a little bit adopt inserting table in in document:

```
\RequirePackage{etex}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textfont=it,             % not used in this MWE
%            labelsep=newline,
%            justification=centering]{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{ skip=1.4pt, labelfont=sc}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\small}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{conthead-text}{font=\small}    
    \SetTblrStyle{contfoot}{font=\footnotesize\itshape}
%---------------- 
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}  
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage{lscape}         % <---- added

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}   % <--- added
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         table-format={(}-1.3{$^{***}$},
         input-open-uncertainty =,
         input-close-uncertainty=,
         table-align-text-before = false
         }

    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {OLS estimation - Dependent variable std\_gpa},
  label = {OLSstd},
remark{Note} = {\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{
                TBW\\
                $^*:\ p<0.1;\quad ^{**}:\ p<0.05;\quad ^{***}:\ p<0.01$.}
                },
                    ]{colspec  = {@{} X[5,l] *{5}{X[c, h, si]} @{}},  %  changed width of the first column
                      row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                        row{1} = {guard},
                  row{even[3]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                      rowhead  = 1,
                     }
    \toprule
% column headers
            &   (1)     &   (2)     &   (3)     &   (4)     &   (5)             \\
    \midrule
% table body is the same ase in the first example
% ...
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}     % added

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please let me know, if my guessing what actually is your problem, is correct. If not, please clarify your question.

In the both environments least table code is a little bit changed (improved) that now code is a wee bit shorted and simpler, and resulted table to my opinion more appealing.

BTW, I would stik with the first example.

Comment: I see you have totally embraced `tabularray`. As I am writing some notes for LaTeX I wanted to ask your opinion, should this be recommended for newcomers to LaTeX in general?

Comment: I found `tabularray` as very promising package with fast development (announced three per year) . However, last year was just one upgrade and recently I didn't see package author on the site (till to last spring was regular contributor here) anymore (but I may overlooked him). This is a bit concerning. Anyway, I will use it in preparation for new edition of one my textbooks .